# Placeholdertext tweak in windows10

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I would like to have a textbox in C# ( XAML ) in windows 10 and have placeholdertext in it, such that when the textbox is empty it shows "Enter Text Here ... " as the placeholder text and when you click on the textbox it shows "Enter Text Here ..." in very small text size in the superscript or subscript.

Answer (score 2):

The TextBox control has a PlaceHolderText property that you can use:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.placeholdertext.aspx

Depending of your exact needs, you might have to edit the Textbox control template/behavior to customize the placeholder but that should be a good start.